# C++ reverse regex_search

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am using std::regex and want to find the last position in a string that matches some user defined regular expression string.

For example given the regex `:.*` and the string "test:55:last", I want to find ":last", not ":55:last".

To clarify, as a user provided regex, I just get their regex plus a "reverse" checkbox, so I can alter the regex, but it must be in a programmatic way.

Comment: Match it this way: `:[^:]+$`

Comment: @revo: If you are posting an answer please do. I already wrote it, but saw your comment.

Comment: I'll if this is what OP looks for.

Comment: Well, there is no other way. Surely, we can use `^.*(:.*)$` but it is not that cool.

Comment: I clarified that as a user provided regex, the intention is to not ask the user to hand craft a different regex (of course if it really cant be done, I have a reason to tell the app designer no)

Comment: Check @WiktorStribiżew's suggestion.

Comment: @FireLancer: At any rate, there is no option to make C++ `std::regex` to analyze the string from right to left (as in .NET).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a user provided regex that you cannot change, but you still need the rightmost match, wrap the pattern with `^.*(` and `)` (or `[\s\S]*` to match across linebreaks) and grab capture group 1 contents:

```
"^.*(:.*)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6m8mYb/1)

The thing is that the above pattern matches

- `^` - the start of string
- `.*` - matches any 0+ characters other than linebreak characters (if you use `[\s\S]*`, all chars will be matched) *as many as possible* (because `*` is a greedy quantifier)
- `(:.*)` - a [**capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that matches `:` and then any 0+ characters other than linebreak characters.

Note that the first `.*` will actually grab as many chars as possible, up to the end of the line (and in most cases, it is the end of the string if there are no linebreaks). Then backtracking occurs, the regex engine will start trying to accommodate text for the subsequent subpatterns (here, it will be the user pattern). Thus, the user subpattern that will get captured will be at the *rightmost* position.

An [example (basic) C++ program](https://ideone.com/RlgSoV) showing how this can work:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string user_pattern(":.*");
    string s("test:55:last");
    regex r("^.*(" + user_pattern + ")");
    smatch matches;
    if (regex_search(s, matches, r)) {
        cout<<matches[1].str();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to explain about the backtracking "trick" used.

Comment: The `[\s\S]*` version worked in all the cases I could think of right now (so in a multi-line document, starting from the last line rather than the first).

Comment: I tried the .* pattern but this causes c++ regex_search to fall into infinite recursion on certain architectures. Crayxc super computer suffers from this behavior.

Comment: @Bobby another solution is to use `:[^:]*$`.

Comment: @Mehrdad The OP problem with `:.*` pattern is complex since `.*` matches `:`, too. The usual approach to match the last occurrence of a pattern is just match multiple occurrences, all of them, and then get/(only) store the last item. Here, it won't work since `.*` will consume the whole rest of the string. Generic use of regex is not always very efficient, custome patterns are more efficient. [`:[^:]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/2SwUgw/1) (17 steps) will perform better than [`.*(:.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/2SwUgw/2) (70 steps).